# Ejb application server in Eclipse development

Tags: eclipse, ejb

I want to develop an EJB project using Eclipse. In the Eclipse development environment, which application server is lightest, easiest and fastest ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Glassfish V3` is probably the lightest one at the moment. It supports the full Java EE 6 platform, yet it starts up in a second or two.

`JBoss AS 6` starts noticeable slower, on my 2.93 Ghz i7 a good 12 seconds in non-debug mode and takes a little longer when starting it in debug mode.

If you're only interested in the web profile of Java EE 6 (which includes EJB lite), then `Caucho Resin` might be a candidate worth looking into. They will officially support only EJB lite, but will nevertheless also implement some of the features from 'normal' EJB, like the extremely handy @Asynchronous annotation as well as message driven beans. See http://blog.caucho.com/?p=384. I haven't used Resin personally, but being 'light' seems to be their first and foremost design choice. At the time of writing, Resin is not yet Java EE 6 Web Profile certified, but this could happen any moment now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JBoss 4 and Eclipse for a project at work. The workflow is OK but I'm stuck with it because of the code. Arun Gupta just released a 5-part screen cast using GlassFish and Eclipse for Java EE development, probably worth checking out.  http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/screencast_31_java_ee_6